# How to select duplicated code from if-statement?

Tags: algorithm, redundancy

I have the following algorithm:

```
if <some1>:
   h += 1
elif <some2>:
   h += 0.5
   i += 1
else:
   i += 1
```

Is it possible to do `i += 1` just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic you want to express is:

```
if <some1>:
   h += 1
else:
   i += 1
   if <some2>:
      h+= 0.5
```

Though it doesn't save you a whole lot.

Comment: Exact seconds :) IMHO, just that the indentation would govern the nesting while writing algorithm.

Comment: This only works if `some2` is not a "subset" of `some1`, e.g., if `some1` is `A and B` and `some2` is `B`, then `h` might end up with `+= 1.5`

Comment: Agreed tobias. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can move it out to the `else` section:

```
if <some1>:
   h += 1
else:
   i += 1
   if <some2>:
      h += 0.5
   else:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if <some1>:
   h += 1
else 
   i +=1
   if <some2>:
     h += 0.5
```

Please check it out